# Hitting timeout using Recaptcha in ASP.NET Options

Tags: recaptcha

need some advice/help here. 
I just started using the Recaptcha library of ASP.NET from this [link](http://code.google.com/apis/recaptcha/docs/aspnet.html)

I've followed the simple guide on that page and it worked well with localhost deployment and development.

However, after I moved the same simple page with Recaptcha to my company's server to test the page out, I hit the below exception when trying to validate the recaptcha word.

> The operation has timed out

I suspect it has something to do with SSL but my company's website 
that I browse, isn't using https, it is just http. I have tried both 
methods, having the recaptcha to set OverrideSecureMode to "true" - it 
didn't work, set it to false, it didn't work as well (such as below)

```
<recaptcha:RecaptchaControl 
            ID="recaptchaControl1" runat="server" 
OverrideSecureMode="True" 
            PublicKey="My_Public_Key" 
            PrivateKey="My_Private_Key" 
        />
```

My code behind, I'm just using a simple button to invoke and display a 
text which work on localhost in Visual Studio:-

```
if (Page.IsValid) 
{ 
  // do the stuff 
} 

else 
  // show the error message from recaptcha
```

What can I do to fix this issue?? Please help.

Answer (score 3):

Sounds like a problem with firewall settings on your company servers. reCAPTCHA requires port 80 outbound (not inbound) to Google servers.